# How can I use 'null coalescing operator' together with converting values if they exists?

Tags: php-7, null-coalescing-operator

This is my code

```
$bookid = (int)$_POST['bookid'] ?? 0;
$userid = (int)$_POST['userid'] ?? 0;
$binding = (int)$_POST['binding'] ?? 0;
$colorpages = (int)$_POST['colorpages'] ?? 0;
```

and I am getting an error: `Undefined index: binding in ...`
I know I am getting this error because I am using `(int)` function to a null variable, but how can i fix this? Convert the value to int and still be able to use the coalescing operator if there is not any value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bookid = (int)($_POST['bookid'] ?? 0);
$userid = (int)($_POST['userid'] ?? 0);
$binding = (int)($_POST['binding'] ?? 0);
$colorpages = (int)($_POST['colorpages'] ?? 0);
```

So `(int)` won't have to deal with the null values